# html2canvas in JQuery isn't calling onrendered

Tags: javascript, jquery, html2canvas

I am trying to take a screenshot of a div inside my html on a button click that also submits that information. I then need this screenshot to be saved onto the server via the script.php. At first I thought it just wasn't catching an error so I put in the console logs for Starting and Rendered. Starting shows but Rendered does not.

Below is my script

```
html2canvas($(".final-print")[0], {
    console.log('starting');
    onrendered: function(canvas) {
    console.log('Rendered');
    var imgsrc = canvas.toDataURL("image/png");
    console.log(imgsrc);
    var dataURL = canvas.toDataURL();
    $.ajax({
       type: "POST",
       url: "script.php",
       data: {
           imgBase64: dataURL
       }
    }).done(function(o) {
        console.log('Check Server For Image');
    });
}
});
```

Below is my html

```
<div class="final-print" style="width:400px;height:300px;padding: 9px;background-image: url('images/back.jpg');background-position: center;background-repeat: no-repeat;background-size: cover;border: 3px solid #000000;"></div>
```

Inside of the console it says 'Starting' with no errors being thrown. Then nothing else happens. The script is called on a button click. After a few hours of research of my own I couldn't really find anything useful to helping fix this issue.

Comment: Are you using an old version of html2canvas? I'm asking because in older versions of html2canvas was used callback method onrendered, then was rewritten to use **Promises**.

Comment: @VladimirGadzhov Should be the newest version I downloaded it off GitHub not that long ago.